# Regex - split time duration from string

Tags: php, regex

I currently have a string that is the title of a video. The  string has annexed a time duration `00:00`. My regex currently is not splitting the tittle and duration. How can accomplish this?

```
print_r(preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#', "The title of video 2:43"));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => The title of video 2:43
)
```

Desired Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => The title of video
    [1] => 2:43
)
```

Comment: This is wrong approach. What if string is: `"Spider Man 3 2:43"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `[a-z]` inside the positive lookbehind and `\d` inside the positive lookahead. Put `\s` inbetween those assertions so that it would split your input according to the in-between space character.

```
print_r(preg_split('#(?<=[a-z])\s(?=\d)#', "The title of video 2:43"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid overmatching when a video title ends in a number, you can try using the following code:

`print_r(preg_split('#(?<=[a-z])\s(?=\d{1,2}\:\d{2})#', "The title of video 2:43"));`